# Angular 12 service worker Sw update is not triggering

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, angular12

In my angular application, I am trying to implement a service worker to update the application without user interaction.

Here is the procedure I m following

1. Make some changes to the application.
2. Run ng build
3. Start an HTTP server with  `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 <dist dir>`

**Expected output**

Application should have automatically refresh

Here is my `update-service`

```
export class CheckforUpdateService {

  constructor(public updates: SwUpdate) { 
    if (updates.isEnabled) {
      interval(10*1000).subscribe(() => updates.checkForUpdate()
        .then(() => console.log('checking for updates')));
    }
  }
  public checkForUpdates(): void {
    console.log('inside')
    this.updates.available.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('avaliable',event)
      this.promptUser()
    }
     );
  }

  private promptUser(): void {
    console.log('updating to new version');
    this.updates.activateUpdate().then(() =>{
      console.log('reloading....')
      document.location.reload()
   
    }); 
  }
}
```

In the app-component.ts  i am calling the update-service method `checkForUpdates()`

```
constructor(private sw: CheckforUpdateService,
    public updates: SwUpdate){
    this.sw.checkForUpdates();

    updates.available.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('current version is', event.current);
      console.log('available version is', event.available);
    });
    updates.activated.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('old version was', event.previous);
      console.log('new version is', event.current);
    });
  }
```

But the problem is  `this.updates.available.subscribe` is not firing even if I try with a new build

In the service worker debug i can see the following logs

```
NGSW Debug Info:

Driver version: 12.2.13
Driver state: NORMAL ((nominal))
Latest manifest hash: d8544c70ccf2d16b487d9ae9ed5f030f946422ba
Last update check: never

=== Version c98cdb909763ddcaa995211951398713e5c081fe ===

Clients: 5c90f84b-45b2-41df-9d08-de009e17f365

=== Version d8544c70ccf2d16b487d9ae9ed5f030f946422ba ===

Clients: c309b1c6-9143-4471-aab6-c721697bd9b6, f5fae64a-8aa6-4140-954c-405fb76f286b

=== Idle Task Queue ===
Last update tick: 300u
Last update run: never
Task queue:
 * init post-load (update)
 * init post-load (cleanup)

Debug log:
```

Also on the network tab I can see some request are failing

[image]

Here is the stack trace of the above request

```
anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2925
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:34
__awaiter @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:20
safeFetch @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2923
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2579
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:34
__awaiter @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:20
fetchLatestManifest @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2578
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2680
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:34
__awaiter @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:20
checkForUpdate @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2677
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2195
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:34
__awaiter @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:20
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2194
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2196
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:34
__awaiter @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:20
handleMessage @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2192
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2149
fulfilled @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:22
step @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:33
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:34
__awaiter @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:20
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2136
onMessage @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2150
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8080/ngsw-worker.js:2057
```

Angular version: 12

NG CLI version: 12.2.13

Comment: You can refer below link. Activated and available event for class SwUpdate is deprecated by angular community in newer version.

https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwUpdate

Comment: It seems that the app cannot read your `ngsw.json` file. Does it exist in your dist dir? e.g. opening `http://localhost:8080/ngsw.json`  in your browser should return the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this with angular 13

```
 import { SwUpdate, VersionReadyEvent } from "@angular/service-worker";
    constructor(private serviceWorkerUpdate: SwUpdate) {} 
    ngOnInit() {
    if (this.serviceWorkerUpdate.isEnabled) {
       this.serviceWorkerSubscription =
        this.serviceWorkerUpdate.versionUpdates.pipe(filter((evt): evt is VersionReadyEvent => evt.type === 'VERSION_READY')).subscribe(() => { 
         location?.reload();
        });
      }
    }
```